# Grails / GORM: Leave out all transient variables on Object.get query?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

i am having a domain class with many transients for calculation purposes. When i do

```
Object.get(params.id)
```

all the transients will be put into the SQL query by GORM. Is there a way to leave those transients out?

Answer (score 0):

in your domain class use

```
class MyDomain {

  int a

  int b

  int c // not transient

  static transients = [ 'a', 'b' ]

}
```

Comment: This also breaks using the transients with gorm... i just wanted to get the
`Object.get(params.id)` without the formula driven transients :/

Comment: the proper `transient`s are ignored by gorm. btw, if you want to use formulas, take a look at https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html

Comment: Yeah the proper transients are ignored, yes, but i cant leave out my formulas (except for a normal `Object.get(params.id)`) :( my customers wont be happy with that and i cant change it to namedqueries, they need it in out reporting tool we build with gorm (users can dynamically choose which columns to show in the reports)